# How to convert string into an IP Address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am using a function to adding . after every three characters inside the string. But how can i remove "0" in front of number.

```
-(NSString *)formatStringAsIpAddress:(NSString*)MacAddressWithoutColon
{
    NSMutableString *macAddressWithColon = [NSMutableString new];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [MacAddressWithoutColon length]; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0)
            [macAddressWithColon appendString:@"."];
        unichar c = [MacAddressWithoutColon characterAtIndex:i];
        [macAddressWithColon appendString:[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&c length:1]];
    }
    return macAddressWithColon;
}
```

If i have ip address 010.000.001.016
How can i set it up like 10.0.1.16? and if i have ip address 192.168.001.001? how to remove front 0's from IP address ?

Comment: Not the more beautiful way but: `NSMutableArray *numberComponents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; for (NSString *aSubString in [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]) { [numberComponents addObject:@([aSubString integerValue])];
 } NSString *final = [numberComponents componentsJoinedByString:@"."];` could do the trick

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of splitting the entire string address with a period to make an array of Int?

Comment: As @El Tomato says - split the string into blocks of three characters, convert those to Int, and create strings from them that don't have the leading zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest:

```
    NSString *ipAddress = @"010.000.001.016";
```

1. **Split** string into array of substrings:

   ```
   NSArray *ipAddressComponents = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
   ```
2. Run through the array with for loop and **convert** each to a int representation:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < ipAddressComponents.count;i++)
   {
       [ipAddressComponents objectAtIndex:i] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[ipAddressComponents objectAtIndex:i]intValue]];
   }
   ```
3. **Join** the array back into a string

   ```
   NSString *newIpAddress = [ipAddressComponents componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
   ```

This should result into getting an IP address: 10.0.1.16

Answer (score 0):

You can use string function and get your expected output with the help of `componentsSeparatedByString` and `componentsJoinedByString` functions.

**Use below method for the same:**

```
-(NSString*)removeZeroPrefix:(NSString*)aStrIP{

    NSMutableArray *subStringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *arrayOfSubString = [aStrIP componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    for (NSString *aSingleString in arrayOfSubString)
    {
        [subStringArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[aSingleString integerValue]]];
    }

    return [subStringArray componentsJoinedByString:@"."];

}
```

**Usage :**

```
[self removeZeroPrefix:@"010.000.001.016"];
[self removeZeroPrefix:@"192.168.001.001"];
```

**Output :**

```
Printing description of aStrIP:
10.0.1.16
Printing description of aStrIP:
192.168.1.1
```

hope this will helps!

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift**

```
let ip = "0125.052.000.10"
        let split = ip.components(separatedBy: ".")
        for number in split {
            if let isNumber = Int(number){
                print(isNumber) // add this isNumber into array which is shows without initial zeros.
            }
        }
```

Finally join created array as String with dot Component